# Why JDK Dynamic proxy can only proxy by interface

Tags: java, proxy

I know that we can proxy class by using cglib. And I want to why JDK Dynamic proxy can only proxy by interface. I have read the source code.

```
/*
* Verify that the Class object actually represents an
* interface.
*/
if (!interfaceClass.isInterface()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        interfaceClass.getName() + " is not an interface");
}
```

In the method of Proxy.newProxyInstance(loader, interfaces, h), it will check the conditions.
I want to know why must be interfaces?It's the standard?

Comment: *Of course* it's the standard. It's what it says in the Javadoc. That question is meaningless. If you want it know *why* it's the standard, it's a more interesting question, but not one you can reasonably expect to get an answer for anywhere outside the Java development team.

Answer (score -1):

Just personal understanding:
    The principle of `JDK` dynamic proxy is to create a new class based on the incoming interface.It can ensure that the generated structure is consistent.
    `Cglib` uses to create a subclass of inheritance classes, use the ASM library to dynamically modify the code to achieve the sub class, so you can use the incoming class reference to implement the proxy class.